# How to access terraform variables in python code?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform

So in my top level main.tf file I have the following

```
module "aws_lambda" {
   ...
   envs = {
      bucket_name = "bucket_name"
      prefix = "prefix"
   }
}
```

Module main.tf

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "descriptive_name" {
   function_name = "${var.prefix}-name
   handler = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
   runtime = "python3.8
   filename = "${path.module}/../../package.zip
   role = var.role_arn
   timeout = 300
   tags = local.default_tags
   vpc_config {
      security_group_ids = var.lambda_security_group_ids
      subnet_ids = var.lambda_subnet_ids
   }
}

locals {
   default_tags = {
     Deployment = var.prefix
   }
{
```

I want to access bucket_name in python code. How can I do this?
I printed using `print(os.environ)` but I do not see the value. I also tried `print(os.getenv("bucket_name"))` but it returns None. I need access to the bucket name to write files to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the module source that has the `aws_lambda_function` resource? It's impossible to tell what's happening otherwise.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I have updated the post. Let me know if more is needed.

Comment: Where does the module use the `envs` variable? It looks like you aren't passing it to the `aws_lambda_function` resource so it won't see it. You'd need to add the [`environment`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#environment) block there to be able to configure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the map of environment variables you want to be accessible from the function code during execution into the `aws_lambda_function` resource:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "descriptive_name" {
    function_name = "${var.prefix}-name"
    handler = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
    runtime = "python3.8"
    filename = "${path.module}/../../package.zip"
    role = var.role_arn
    timeout = 300
    tags = local.default_tags
    vpc_config {
        security_group_ids = var.lambda_security_group_ids
        subnet_ids = var.lambda_subnet_ids
    }
    environment {
        variables = var.envs
    }
}
```

See the [Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function) for `aws_lambda_function`.